# filter rows based on combination of words

Tags: python, r, text, filtering, words

I have a data-frame with a column consisting of comma separated words. I want to filter rows with exact combination of words

```
text
a,boy,and,a,girl
mummy, and, papa
teach, learn
teach, learn
teach
```

for eg: I want rows with teach,learn only

Comment: which language you are using? Python or R?

Comment: any of them, preferably r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df <- data.frame(column_name = c("text", "a,boy,and,a,girl", "teach", "teach, learn"))
```

This gives is how the data frame would look like. Then you can do the following filter using dplyr package:

```
test <- df %>% filter(grepl("teach|text", column_name))
```

Comment: data.frame(column_name = c("a,boy,and,a,girl", "teach", "teach, learn"))
test <- df %>% filter(grepl("teach|text", column_name)). This given both "teach" and "teach, learn", whereas i want only "teach, learn"

Comment: the result of ur command is    column_name
1        teach
2 teach, learn whereas I want only teach,learn

Comment: how to search if i have both teach, learn and learn, teach in two different rows, what should be the solution. as grepl searches for pattern. Do i have to give both patterns or is their any short cut

Comment: Try this: 
    `df <- data.frame(column_name = c("text", "a,boy,and,a,girl", "teach", "teach, learn", "learn, teach"))`
    `test <- df %>% filter(grepl("teach |learn", column_name))`